# How to store actual item name in table if I'm using dropdownlist.selectedindex? I'm using tinyint for Gender

Tags: c#, asp.net

Data gets stored in table but for gender its giving me index value 0 or 1 but I want actual string "Male" or "Female".

Check Dropdownlist1.SelectedIndex

```
Employee employee = new Employee();
employee = employee.SetValues(
    Guid.NewGuid(), 
    TextBox1.Text,
    DropDownList1.SelectedIndex, 
    TextBox2.Text.TrimEnd(),
    TextBox3.Text, 
    TextBox4.Text, 
    TextBox5.Text, 
    TextBox6.Text.TrimEnd(), 
    Convert.ToInt32(TextBox7.Text), 
    TextBox8.Text, 
    TextBox9.Text, 
    ComboBox1.SelectedValue
);
```

Comment: i would strongly recommend searching for an online tutorial for this type of question

Comment: I would strongly recommend naming your textboxes so that no one (including you) ends up guessing which one is which.

Comment: Try `SelectedText` instead of `SelectedValue` for the gender control.

Answer (score 0):

We can use Dropdownlist1.SelectedItem.Text property to get the text of selected item

Comment: i have made a class employee and declared variable Gender as int. so it doesnt accept selecteditem or selectedvalue.. If I change variable datatype to string and set selecteditem.text then the code runs but it doesnt store the values in table nor it displays data on gridview.

Comment: in the database what is the type of your column if it is int or tinyint then change it to the varchar(10) and then try